psconfig -passphrase exit with The passphrase parameter specified with the upgrade command is missing or invalid
Hello to all every time i ran
psconfig -cmd upgrade -inplace b2b -passphrase "Type your Farm Pass Phrase" -wait

I get the error:
The passphrase parameter specified with the upgrade command is missing or invalid.
sharepoint 2016
tried with single quote, double quote and without quote.
I cannot find any example nor any documentation on how escape the actual passphrase
thanks

I don't think you need passphrase parameter for psconfig.exe
See this article
PSConfig -cmd upgrade -inplace b2b -wait -force


Also, before using passphrase needs to be secured like:
$configPassphrase = "Your plain text passphrase"  
$s_configPassphrase = (ConvertTo-SecureString -String $configPassphrase -AsPlainText -force)



currently -passphrase  seems to be accepted see this article

Never seen passphrase parameter for PSConfig. You may try without it. See here and also here
